# how do I query this relation with eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and eloquent obviously.
I have 4 models and tables.
`1 => city 
2 => location
3 => venue 
4 => tag`
now bear with me to describe relationship.
a **city** has many **locations** and a **location** belongs to a **city**.
a **location** belongs to a **venue** and a **venue** has one **location**.
a **venue** belongs to many **tags** and a **tag** belongs to many **venue** (Many to many relationship)

 Here are the query I wanna executed.
given A city, how can I filter venues of that city based on tags.
example: for city Austin I wanna get venues that have tag "special".

and Also, how many queries are executed for perform this task.Is it efficient to perform this kind of task with this database model.

I tried to be as explicit as possible but if some parts seems vague for you, please don't hesitate to ask.
thanks

Comment: you have to go through hierarchy. u can get locations for that city and from locations u can get venues. u cannot get venues for a city becoz it has no direct relation with the city model.

Comment: @Jamal Abdul Nasir  yeah I know that, but problem is filtering the results.

Comment: for you query, might be easier to add the relationship for City <-> Venue. So a city has many venue, a venue belongs to a city. This way you can get all the venues by tag and then filter by city.

Comment: use query builder to create one query to retrieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent query below filters result based on relationship:
`$venues = Venue::whereHas('location', function($query) use ($city) {
    $query->where('city_id',$city->id);
})->get();`